# How to handle both reactive and mvc ServerHttpRequest in a same @ControllerAdvice?

Tags: java, spring

I have code like this below :

```
MyExceptionHandler {
  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public Object handleMvc(Exception ex, org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest request) {
    return request.getbody;
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public Object handleReactive(Exception ex, org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest request) {
    return request.getBody();
  }
}
```

The code above produces `IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for Exception` error.

Is there a way to handle both MVC and reactive requests in the `ControllerAdvice`? I'm working on a common project that works across multiple projects using different httprequest type.

Answer (score 0):

```
**In spring boot using this**    
package com.example.demo.exception;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

    @ControllerAdvice
    public class UserCVExceptionController {


        @ExceptionHandler(value = UserCVNotfoundException.class)
           public ResponseEntity<Object> exceptionMsg(UserCVNotfoundException exception) {
            Map<String, String> headers=new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Status", "404");
            headers.put("Message", "User Not found");
            headers.put("User", exception.getEmail());

             return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

           }

    }
```

Comment: I need to get the request body to populate the response.